# Как в python найти центр фото?

Tags: python, pil

Нужно через PIL наложить фото в центр фотографии, изображение может быть любым размером так что надо найти не подбором а кодом? Как это сделать?

Comment: Может быть длину и ширину разделить на 2?

Comment: В pillow координаты изображения начинаются с левого верхнего угла, т.е. увеличиваются вправо и вниз. Я бы вычислял как раз левый верхний угол этого нового фото внутри старого. X = (длина_старого_фото - длина_нового_фото) / 2. Y = (высота_старого_фото - высота_нового_фото) / 2. Потом с помощью метода paste наложить изображение.